# Close all the tabs and redirect to login page on Logout button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net

The user can open multiple tab and works on every tab simultaneously, I want when the user click log out button then the user should be logged out from all the tabs and redirected to login page

Comment: If user logs out then close the session of that user, so when he refreshes the page and session is not available take the user to Login Page

Comment: Tried using Session.Close() and Session.abandon() But not working

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the logout button, add this code:

```
Session.Abandon();
```

This will destroy the session of the currently logged in use. You can't close a tab. However, with the Session.Abandon method when they refresh any open tabs after hitting log out, they'll automatically be directed to login.

```
Response.Redirect(webpage name);
```

Response.Redirect is what redirects a user to a page. So on every page when it loads, check if the session is null. If it is, use Response.Redirect to go to the login page.

Comment: Session.Abandon is not working for all tabs, it is only closing the current tabs session value. but that session id is being continued in other tabs. please suggest some other methods

Comment: You can't "close tabs". You can disconnect an application from its user. But you can't remote control the browser.

Even the current tab can't close itself.